# Significance of a Native American sign

Tags: yellowstone

In the *Yellowstone* season 3 episode 8, after Mo kills Monica'a attacker, he draws a horse shoe (U shape) on the ground and places what looks like wood shavings in the opening.

Can someone please explain this? What is the significance of this Native American ritual/expression?

[image]